# Running VMWare Player on Win 7 - error "The system cannot find the file "" (code: 3)."

Tags: vmware-player

I just had trouble running VMWare player (version 3.1.0 build-261024) on Win 7 and got this error:

Error while powering on: The following error occurred when starting VMware Player.W32AuthConnectionLaunch: Reply error "The system cannot find the file "" (code: 3).".

I Googled the error and turns out the fix is to run VMWare Player as Administrator.

I decided to paste the error and fix here so this site would also include the fix :)

(I hope this get's indexed by google)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix is to run VMWare Player as Administrator :)